# Android 2.1 Emulator doesn't load, even after waiting a long time

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I'm trying to get into Android app developing. My first problem is actually getting the emulator to run. I am using the official Hello World tutorial to get me started, and it works fine with my 4.0.3 AVD, but when I try it with a new 2.1 AVD (also created the project from start using 2.1), the emulator doesent load up.

Although it tries to load, the "Android" letters from the start are not with the usual font, they just apear as a "Typewriter" type font with a underscore after, and when they disapear, nothing shows up. I have waited up to 1 hour for it to boot, to no avail.

I already searched stackoverflow for answers, but since I dont have a significant error showing up, I can't find the answer.

My log is the following:

```
[2012-02-07 11:23:09 - Hello World 21] Android Launch!
[2012-02-07 11:23:09 - Hello World 21] adb is running normally.
[2012-02-07 11:23:09 - Hello World 21] Performing com.hello.world.HelloWorld21Activity activity launch
[2012-02-07 11:23:09 - Hello World 21] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD '2.1'
[2012-02-07 11:23:09 - Hello World 21] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device '2.1'
[2012-02-07 11:23:14 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Unable to create sensors port: Unknown error
[2012-02-07 11:23:14 - Hello World 21] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-02-07 11:23:14 - Hello World 21] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

Running Eclipse Classic with the ADT plugin, and the normal Android SDK, following every instruction on http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html .

Thank you!

Comment: It really takes a LOOOOONG time in the first run!

Comment: I don't even see it load. Its just a black screen with no movement whatsoever. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered a similar problem with the emulator startup when using the 64bit version of Windows 7. I couldn't get it to start with a 2.1 or 2.2 AVD (I experienced a similar behavior as the one you describe), however I did not try an AVD for newer OS versions than 2.3. So if you are running on a 64 bit OS, I would suggest you to try a 32-bit version - it helped in my case.

Comment: I realize my answer is not really a solution to the problem, but I did try to search for a way to get the emulator running correctly on Win7 64-bit. But I didn't manage to find a working solution.

Comment: Thanks, it did help. I was precisely running Windows 7 64bits OS, so It might have been the problem. Using eclipse classic 32x seem to have fixed it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Android Emulator is rather slow software. It's start up speed depends directly on your hardware. Also appearing of "Typewriter" Android label is typical for Android 2.x versions. 
Try to reboot the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Took my time but I fixed the problem.

Just use your integrated graphic card as default graphic processor. 
If you are using a CUDA capable (or similar) graphic card disable it. Just don´t run your software (eclipse, AVD...) with your CUDA graphic processor. Eclipse produces assert errors with CUDA and AVD stops working. Flash player doesn't work either with CUDA enabled.

That worked for me, lucky I'm using a laptop.